# How does web developer make use of Adobe XD?

Tags: adobe-xd, front-end-development

I am a beginner in web development and design and I want to make my websites more attractive.

So, I have started learning Adobe XD. But I cannot see how exactly I am going to make use of it in actual web development.

I know we'll get an idea of how a web page will look like. Can anyone explain to me the exact process of designing and developing a page using Adobe XD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adobe XD helps with **prototyping**.

You can't build functioning websites in XD, but you can create protypes (or mockups) of what the site should look like, how buttons and styles should interact with user input (to a limited extent).

In my work, we have a designer who will create a mockup in XD which we then hand to our developers to actually convert it into a live and functioning site.

The designer is the one who works with the client to ensure that they are getting what they want. XD also provides a faster method to show "working" samples to the client and get their feedback.

---

There are cases where for super simple mockups you know you can make it in HTML/CSS much faster and without much need for XD... (I've done this before) it's a case by case basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the softwares like Adobe XD , Figma, Sketch you can design user interfaces but when we hand the screens or files to the developer so that he could create the application we need a tool i.e zeplinor avocode in which we upload our files and developers extracts assets from it like icons and font size or color.